# How to know if the user is using multiple monitors

Tags: c#, .net, c++, winapi

I'm trying to figure out a way to know if the user is using multiple monitors.

I would like to know how to do this in native C++ (using the Win32 API) and with managed code (using the .NET Framework).

Thanks in advance

Comment: some very elegant Linq code in C# here by Rob Fonseca-Ensor which will calculate the bounds of all current screens in use : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176648/screen-overlay-for-screenshot/2176683#2176683

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can give you C# .NET:

```
if (Screen.AllScreens.Length > 1)
{
    // Multiple monitors
}
```

**Edit:** A search on Google turned up the following. It mentions 98/ME so it might no be relevant but may point you in the right direction:

*There are new APIs for handling multiple monitors in Windows 98. The APIs used in the monitors class sample are GetMonitorInfo, MonitorFromWindow and MonitorFromRect.*

*The GetSystemMetrics API has some new constants (see below) that can be used to determine the metrics of a multiple monitor system. The GetSystemMetrics API returns information about the Windows environment. This API can be used to determine how many monitors are on the system, whether they are set at the same display format, and the size of the virtual desktop.*

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/194578

Comment: Thank you.
Both answers were accurate.
I was able to get the number of monitors using the GetSystemMetrics function passing as argument the SM_CMONITORS constant.

Answer (score 6):

In .NET it's as simple as using the [Screen.AllScreens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens.aspx).Length property. Not too sure about C++ though.

Answer (score 6):

[GetSystemMetrics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724385(VS.85).aspx) with `SM_CMONITORS` and off you go...

Comment: Had a feeling it was `GetSystemMetrics`.

Comment: Using three monitors on a daily basis I needed to learn this fast ;>

Answer (score 2):

Just to document here the C/C++ solution:

```
int iMonitors = GetSystemMetrics(SM_MONITORS);
```